# Unir tablas con Entity Framework sin clave ajena/foránea

Tags: c#, entity-framework

¿Sería posible con Entity Framework obtener todos los objetos de una tabla que cumplan un criterio que se encuentra en otra tabla?

El quid de la cuestión es que ambas tablas NO tienen relación explícita con una foreign key.

En SQL sería relativamente fácil, porque puedo unir ambas tablas con un JOIN y sacar los campos que pertenecen a una de las tablas.

Pero, ¿y en Entity Framework? ¿Cómo uno dos tablas, y hago que me devuelva los objetos de sólo una de ellas?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que necesitas es hacer join con LINQ.

Aqui ahi un ejemplo que encontre

```
 var customers = new Customer[]
    {
        new Customer{ID = 5, Name = "Sam"},
        new Customer{ID = 6, Name = "Dave"},
        new Customer{ID = 7, Name = "Julia"},
        new Customer{ID = 8, Name = "Sue"}
    };

    // Example orders.
    var orders = new Order[]
    {
        new Order{ID = 5, Product = "Book"},
        new Order{ID = 6, Product = "Game"},
        new Order{ID = 7, Product = "Computer"},
        new Order{ID = 8, Product = "Shirt"}
    };

    // Join on the ID properties.
    var query = from c in customers
                join o in orders on c.ID equals o.ID
                select new { c.Name, o.Product };
```

Fuente https://www.dotnetperls.com/join

En este ejemplo puedes hacer un join con las tablas sin que tengan relación la unes y la comparas con la columna correspondiente.

Answer (score 0):

Pues al final encontré la solución utilizando LINQ.

En este ejemplo, tengo dos tablas, usuarios y roles, las cuales no tienen relación con claves ajenas:

```
        using (var db = new mydatabaseEntities1())
        {

            var x = from
                    u in db.Usuarios
                    join r in db.Roles on u.rol equals r.Id
                    where r.descripcion == "ADMIN"
                    select u;
         }
```

Comment: Eso fue lo que te publique arriba hace 23 minutos